# Getting undefined JSON path, but data is available in console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, weather

I'm using Redux Toolkit for the first time. Data is successfully available in the console, but when i try to render data in the UI, i'm getting undefined JSON path {`${weather[0].description} ${weather[0].main}`} Maybe i need to check something with if() statement but i don't know how and where. My own if() solution didn't do the trick in App.js

JSON data

```
description: "broken clouds"
icon: "04n"
id: 803
main: "Clouds"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

App.js side

````
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchWeatherAction } from './redux/slices/weatherSlices';


function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchWeatherAction('Seoul'));
  }, []);
  
  const state = useSelector(state => state.weather);
  const { loading, weather, error } = state || {};

  if(!weather){
    return null
  }

  console.log(weather);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      {weather.map((weather, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <div>{`${weather[0].description} ${weather[0].main}`}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;```


Redux Toolkit side

``` import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
 import axios from 'axios';

 export const fetchWeatherAction = createAsyncThunk(
        'weather/fetch',
        async (payload, {rejectWithValue, getState, dispatch})=>{
            try{
                const {data} = await axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${payload}&appid=7469e38d322111e34a7027db2eee39c3`);
                return data;
            }catch(error){
                if(!error?.response){
                    throw error
                }
                return rejectWithValue(error?.response?.data);
            }
        }
 );

    const weatherSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'weather',
        initialState: {},
        extraReducers: builder => {
            builder.addCase(fetchWeatherAction.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.loading = true;
            });
            builder.addCase(fetchWeatherAction.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.weather = action?.payload;
                state.loading = false;
                state.error = undefined;
            });
            builder.addCase(fetchWeatherAction.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.loading = false;
                state.weather = undefined;
                state.error = action?.payload;
            })
        },
    });

    export default weatherSlice.reducer;```
````

Comment: I've tried to answer your question, but it's worth noting that there's *a lot* of extraneous code here. Please in the future try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, you might provide some mock data (I don't have access to your API, so I can't reproduce this) and then trim down the rest of the code as much as possible so only the problematic part remains. You might even be able to figure out the problem yourself this way!

Comment: It worked perfectly, indexing was the problem. I  noted your feedback and I'll try to be more succinct in the future. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Make sure to accept the answer if you believe it addressed your question. Upvoting and accepting good answers is the SO version of saying "thanks," and it also helps guide anyone who might come across the same problem in the future and wants to quickly see what you/the community thought was the most helpful information. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are mapping `weather`, which looks like an array of objects, and then trying to index into that object as e.g. `weather[0]...`. If `weather` inside the map operation is in fact an object and not an array, this will not work. I think what you want is something like the following. Note that I've changed the name of the interior variable to `weatherItem` for clarity:

```
{weather.map((weatherItem, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <div>{`${weatherItem.description} ${weatherItem.main}`}</div>
  </div>
))}
```